# Why these codes about the timer(setTimeout()), the then() method of Promises running like this?

Tags: javascript, promise, frontend, settimeout, asynchronous-javascript

```
const wait = function () {
  return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
    resolve()
    setTimeout(console.log('a'), 5000)
  })
}
 
wait().then(() => console.log('b'))
```

Explain the code:

As you can see above, i created a `wait()` function that return a promise, and in this function, the `resolve()` will be executed immediately, and a timer that will log 'a' message after 5 seconds.

What I expected:

So what i expected is that the `then()` method will be executed, it move to the `then()` method immediately, so from here it will log the 'b' message. And because of 5 seconds timer waiting in the background, in the Web API, the 'a' message will be log after the 'b' message.

What it actually did:

But the result is so different, the 2 messages are both logged at the same time immediately and the 'a' is before the 'b', the 5 seconds didn't pass yet. Can you guys help me to explain, i dont really understand, i think my understand of the `then()` method is wrong, so please help me to repair if you know, thank you so much!

Comment: wrap console.log in a function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You call `wait()`
2. `wait` creates a new Promise
3. `resolve()` **immediately** resolves that promise, but the function `resolve` appears in continues to run before the anything is done about that
4. You call `console.log('a')` (assuming the missing `)` is a typo in the question and not the real code) which logs `a`
5. The return value of `console.log` (which is `undefined`) is passed to `setTimeout` (which does nothing because it isn't a function).
6. The function ends
7. The promise resolution takes place
8. The `then` function is called
9. `console.log('b')` logs `b`.

Comment: Oh thank you so much, i fixed my problems, thank you very much friend now the code is working like i expected!

Answer (score -2):

you just have errors in how u call setTimeout

```js
const wait = function() {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    resolve()
    setTimeout(() => console.log('a'), 5000)
  })
}

wait().then(() => console.log('b'))
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding *how* and/or *why* it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.